# How to reveal underlying image using css or js

Tags: javascript, css, animation, background-image

I want to have one image above another one that is being revealed on scroll. 
I am thinking of a similar effect as on this page: https://affinity.serif.com/de/photo/ (live-filters section, called "fixed-scroll" here).

Preferrably a native CSS solution or with as little JS as possible.

So far, I've found this example https://tympanus.net/Blueprints/ScrollingLayout/
It's almost what I want but I can't think of a way to make the background-attachment fixed to the element's parent rather than the whole viewport. 
It only works when it's fullscreen and there's nothing above this effect.

I've also thought about a solution using translate-y but can't find a way to slide the top image up revealing the image underneath instead of sliding the lower image upon the first one.

Can you help me out here or point me in the right direction, how this may be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Try inspecting the source for the examples you linked to see what they did

Comment: From the source I was able to tell that it uses Javascript and it's using scrollTop to achieve the scrolling. As I'm not very fond using JS, I was looking for a CSS solution. Another example I've found on StackOverflow uses quite the same methods but also only for fullscreen-scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know using `background-attachment: fixed` might be the only way to achieve this particular effect using only CSS, but it looks like that doesn't quite solve your problem.

I would try a simple parallax scrolling library such as [parallax.js](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/). This uses javascript to achieve the desired effect but you can apply all the code via CSS data attributes, like so:

```
<div id="mydiv" data-parallax="scroll" data-speed="0" data-image-src="/path/to/image.jpg"></div>
```

With `data-speed="0"` the image inside the div will be stationary as you scroll past.